# Bound volume charge distribution in dielectrics

Tags: electric-fields, dielectric

**Problem**

Calculate the potential produced by a distribution of charge  at a point $r$ in a dielectric material.

The expression of $V$ at a point outside the charge distribution (a molecule), but inside the dielectric material is $$V(r)=V_{\rho}(r) + V_{\sigma}(r)$$ where  $\rho$ is the distribution charge (of a solute). I do not understand why there is no potential produced for the bond volume charge distribution $\rho_b$.

How do we know if there is a $\rho_b$ in a dielectric (due to an external electric field)?

I have read that sometimes that $\rho_b$ is zero in some dielectrics but do not know how to prove it.

Any help?

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Regardless, we need some information about the specific geometry to give concrete guidance.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake It is an arbitrary geometry..(any solute). It is not a homework problem. I do not understand why there is no potential produced by $\rho_{b}$

Comment: Geometry doesn't refer to the content (solute) but to the shape of the container and the applied electric field.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake But the geometry is arbitrary, a charged molecule that is the source of electric field inside an infinite dielectric

Comment: @SeanE.Lake i think there should be a way to prove there is no potential produced by $\rho_{b}$ or something like that

Comment: See @velutluna's answer, and keep in mind that $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E} = 0$ when no charge is present, so the dielectric just reduces the effective charge of point charges inside of it.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake And why divergence of E is zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59662/discussion-between-sean-e-lake-and-santimirandarp).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the polarization density, $\mathbf{P}$, is the volume density of dipole moments. The definition of the [displacement field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field), $\mathbf{D}$, is:
$$\mathbf{D} = \epsilon_0 \mathbf{E} + \mathbf{P}.$$
Take the divergence of both sides and you get the relationship among free charge, total charge, and bound charge densities:
$$\rho_{\mathrm{free}} = \rho_{\mathrm{net}} + \nabla\cdot \mathbf{P}.$$
As you can see, the bound charge density, defined as $\rho_{\mathrm{net}} - \rho_{\mathrm{free}}$, is given by $\rho_{\mathrm{bound}} = -\nabla\cdot \mathbf{P}$.

Also, note that just like you can have surface charge densities from discontinuous changes in the electric field, you can have surface bound charge densities. If you recall, the change in the component of the electric field perpendicular to a surface charge is given by $\Delta \mathbf{E}_\perp = \frac{\sigma_{\mathrm{net}}}{\epsilon_0}$, thus you also have 
\begin{align}
\Delta \mathbf{D}_\perp &= \sigma_{\mathrm{free}} \\
\Delta \mathbf{P}_\perp &= -\sigma_{\mathrm{bound}}.
\end{align}

Also, keep in mind that $\mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{P}$ don't have vanishing curls, the way $\mathbf{E}$ does. So, if we take the curl of the definition equation we get:
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{D} = \nabla \times \mathbf{P}.$$
This means that the component of $\mathbf{E}$ that is parallel to a surface ($\mathbf{E}_{||}$) cannot change discontinuously, but if $\mathbf{P}_{||}$ changes discontinuously across a surface, then so must $\mathbf{D}_{||}$:
$$\Delta \mathbf{D}_{||} = \Delta \mathbf{P}_{||}.$$

An example of a problem where this last property is important is if you imagine placing a large flat dielectric sheet at an angle with respect to an externally applied electric field and you want to find the resulting $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{D}$, and $\mathbf{P}$.